# How to set an (environment) variable in the build script in Gitlab CI?

Tags: bash, build, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab

I have a dummy build script in the `Gitlab CI`:

```
pwd
ci_app_path=$(pwd)
echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
```

and I get this output when the system start the build process:

```
pwd
/home/kai/gitlab-runners/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-1

ci_app_path=$(pwd)

echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
INFO: current directory:
```

so the variable was not set (or was set only for that line: as I know each line executed separately)

I heard about push/pop mechanism to reach the functionality I desired, but could not find any details, how to implement that.

## Update:

as I thought, each line is going executed separately. So the variable scope is only one line, where it is defined:

script:

```
pwd
ci_app_path=$(pwd) && echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
```

output:

```
pwd
/home/devuser/gitlab-runners/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-1

ci_app_path=$(pwd) && echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
INFO: current directory: /home/kai/gitlab-runners/gitlab-ci-runner/tmp/builds/project-1
```

I don't think that writing the whole script as a one-liner is a good idea/practice.

How to get the variables set while executing the build script?

## P.S.

actually I wonder why the whole build script must contain no empty lines?, otherwise it returns:

```
No such file or directory
```

and a build fails on this place

Comment: I'm not familiar with `gitlab`, but this is the same type of issue faced with `make` (perhaps that is what `gitlab ci` uses?). With `make`, the idea is that if you have that many lines, you should save them to an external script and have `make` execute it. The `Makefile` is not a shell script, and should not be treated as one. `gitlab ci` may take the same approach.

Answer (score 10):

Gitlab CI just plays shell commands so do what you do in *sh:

```
export ci_app_path=$(pwd)
echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
```

Answer (score 1):

By the time Gitlab-CI folks fix it, you may create a Makefile and export variables inside it and in Gitlab-CI pass the variables, for example

PWD=$PWD make

Makefile starts with a:
export GOPATH=$(PWD)