# GitLab CI/CD permission denied when mounting volume for docker

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

For the past few days I have been trying to setup a GitLab pipeline for my Laravel application, so that it installs, tests, builds and deploys to my kubernetes cluster. However, when i am trying to install composer using the following line:

```
docker run --volume $(pwd):/app --rm $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install $COMPOSER_ARGS
```

I am getting a permission denied error on the $(pwd) command. This is the error:

```
/scripts-66-218/step_script: eval: line 153: /builds/my-project/laravel-api: Permission denied
```

I am not an expert in GitLab CI/CD, but I do know my ways with dockers etc, but in this case I don't exactly know why I am getting this permission denied. The files are readable for every user, so I am not sure, but that seems correct. This is the full composer pipeline code:

```
composer-install-production:
  extends: .custom-composer-install
  variables:
      COMPOSER_ARGS: "--ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-scripts"
  before_script:
    - echo $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL --password-stdin
    - cp .env.pipeline .env
  only:
    - tags


.custom-composer-install:
  extends: .composer-install
  variables:
    COMPOSER_TAG: "2"
    COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY: $GITLAB_RUNNER_RSA
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .env
      - public/
      - vendor/
      - storage/

.composer-install:

  # Default variables
  variables:
    COMPOSER_TAG:             "prestissimo" # Change composer tag to use a differrent version. 
    COMPOSER_ARGS:            "--ignore-platform-reqs --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist" # If provided, composer arguments are added to the install.
    COMPOSER_AUTHJSON:        "" # If provided, authentication can be added to install private packages like Nova.
    COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY:  "" # If provided, adds an SSH key to the composer image to access private packages.

  stage: install

  before_script:
    - echo $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_USERNAME $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL --password-stdin

  script:
    - $(pwd)
    - >
      if [ "$COMPOSER_AUTHJSON" != "" ]; then
        echo $COMPOSER_AUTHJSON > auth.json
      fi
    - >
      if [ "$COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY" == "" ]; then
        docker run --volume $PWD:/app --rm $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install $COMPOSER_ARGS
      else
        docker run --volume $PWD:/app --rm -e "SSH_DEPLOY_KEY=$COMPOSER_SSH_DEPLOY_KEY" $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install --ignore-platform-reqs $COMPOSER_ARGS
      fi

  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_ID-$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
    expire_in: 1 day
    paths:
      - vendor/

  interruptible: true
```

And the script crashes on this line:

```
- $(pwd)
```

Does somebody know what is going on here and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first test if using pws instead of $(pwd) (which executes a command in a subshell) would work:

```yaml
script:
    - pwd
    - >
      ...
```

You would find $(pwd) when you want to assign the current working directory to a variable, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19359905/6309).

```
ci_app_path=$(pwd) && echo "INFO: current directory: $ci_app_path"
```

Comment: `pwd` does work, instead of `$(pwd)`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Great! Does that answer your question then?

Comment: So is this the new line that I need to use the: `docker run --volume pwd:/app --rm $CONTAINER_REGISTRY_URL/internal/docker/composer:${COMPOSER_TAG} install $COMPOSER_ARGS`? Just `pwd`?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I meant using pwd in the script part of your composer pipeline code, not in the docker command.

Comment: Okay, I created a variable with: `PROJECT_PATH=$(pwd)`. Then for my docker mounting I did: `--volume $PROJECT_PATH:/app`. But my original problem was that when running this docker, I get `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app`. But in the script when I run `cd $PROJECT_PATH && ls`, I see all my project files, including the composer.json?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk Your original issue was "I am getting a permission denied error on the `$(pwd)` command." So on the execution of the docker compose script, no?

Comment: Yes I first mounted the docker volume with `$(pwd):/app`, but then I got the no `composer.json` error. This was caused by the fact that `$(pwd)` resulted in permission denied. Now with the inline variable that you described, I am still getting the `composer.json `not found error.... However, I can see with Las that the directory of the inline variable does contain the `composer.json`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252155/discussion-between-vonc-and-a-vreeswijk).